# Can I make a folder accessible only to my program?

Tags: python

We're doing a school project creating student databases for teachers, and we'd like to make it more secure by making the folder containing the student files accessible only by the program. Is this possible, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: It depends upon the operating system. On Linux and Posix, you probably can (using [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) techniques...)

Comment: If it's a school project, you probably don't need to, but if you want security I'd imagine it would be easier to encrypt the files in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: It depends ;).

To be more specific: It depends on your operating system and the rights management you are having there.

e.g. on UNIX, you could create dedicated user account which is used to run your programm and allow rw-access to the files/folders only to this user.

On Windows, it will be more difficult.

In general, you should try to get a feeling about how possible attacs might be performed (USB-stick, login via internet / intranet, bribing someone, ...), then consider the likelyhood and perform good countermeasures against this attack.

Personally, I prefer

1. Backups located at more then one place
2. Good access logging
3. threatening with legal actions
4. And, **most important: strong passwords!!!**

Comment: You could (potentially, haven't checked it) use `win32api` in Python if you're using Windows. With Unix platforms it will probably be a lot more straightforward and won't require a dedicated api.